# Drupal, Lightbox: cannot edit the content inside

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, lightbox

I'm using Drupal and Lightbox module to display the content of articles in this website: donatellabernardi.ch/drupal
if you click on an article the lightbox is displayed.

However I have 2 problems with it:

1) I cannot use the libraries such as the tooltip library qTip from it. (If you move the mouse over the balls, you'll see the tooltips)

2) I cannot invert the title with the balls (tags), because it seems that the template of the node in the lightbox is not controlled by my theme. I tried also to change the node template (in the drupal root folder), swapping title and meta data but it didn't work.

thanks

Comment: The usage of the word "balls" in your question almost made me fall off the chair laughing :D (sorry for an offtopic comment)

Comment: ahah, it was to make the question more interesting. Anyway if you can provide a solution would be great, since I'm really stuck.

Comment: Alas, I cannot. I've never used Lightbox or qTip before :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with the awesome simpletooltip plugin